# DNS alias for old path/server *redirection maybe*

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2022

We have an old Windows Server  2008. This was end of life in 2020 and needs to be shutdown.

We have an replacement Windows Server 2022 host.

On the old server we have an `\\servername\share`.

On the new server we have the same `\\servername\share`.

Now we want to shutdown the old 2008 server and going further with the 2022 server.

The question i have is.

Is it possible that if you search via the old server `\\oldservername\share` you automatically goes to the new server `\\newservername\share`?

The old server will be shutdown, and we need to search from old to new one.

I have setup the NTFS permissions  on the new server.

[both servers are in the DNS list, and joined to the domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Yh6.png)

Comment: The simplest solution is to give the new server the name of the old one (rename the old one if you wish to keep it for the moment). Otherwise, you could look into organizing your network with [DFS Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/dfs-overview).

Comment: For Kerberos to work with the old server's name, you must at least register that SPN to the new server. This can be done via renaming the server, or by adding an additional name with `NETDOM COMPUTERNAME CurrentName /ADD AltName.fq.dn` https://serverfault.com/a/824089/411612